# How can I run multiple instances of a SOAP web service in SOA enterprise manager?

Tags: oracle, web-services, soap, soapui, soa

I have created a synchronous SOAP web service in S.O.A. I'm using S.O.A enterprise manager to test it. What I want to do is to run multiple instances of it at a time. In S.O.A EM only one instance can be tested at a time.
Is there a way to run like 1000 instances of it so I can check the workload?
Is there a way to do it in S.O.A EM or do i have to use another software?

What I have tried is to open multiple windows of EM at a time, but it is not applicable when there are 1000 instances.

Comment: Hello, this question might belong to  [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/)

Comment: I tried to find the answer on Server fault, but no one asked it there.

Comment: Maybe YOU should ask it then there? Be the first.

Comment: It says,i have to wait 40 minutes now to ask another question. Maybe because stackoverflow and serverfault accounts are connected.

Comment: Ok, it might be because there is a migration check going on whether this question belongs to SF. If it does then this question will be migrated there. If not - well - then i was wrong and i am sorry about the delay. But anyway you have an answer already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enterprise manager is not suitable for advanced testing. You can just check that the service is alive and responds properly.

For functional testing I recommend using [**SoapUI**](https://www.soapui.org). SoapUI is also capable for performance testing, but for higher workload I recommend [**JMeter**](http://jmeter.apache.org).

Comment: Thank you, this was exactly i was looking for. I am using SoapUI.\